# Textbox cant be selected or set to focus

Tags: css, html, webgl, o3d

I am using the latest Minefield and Chrome nightly builds; at the official O3D webgl samples (ie.http://o3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples_webgl/o3d-webgl-samples/customcamera.html) I cant change any of the text in the non-disabled html text boxes. I have the same problem with my own pages when using O3D (haven't tested raw webgl script but I am now using o3d *eek*) .. and this is a problem now that I have gotten to the point where I require an overlaying interface for my 3D shiz

Is anyone else having this problem, has investigated the problem, or is able to provide any knowledge or analysis of this BUG ?

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: You have to right click them in both browsers .. why is left click disabled??

Comment: I am now using Chrome version 9 (stable release?) and still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!!!!!!!!!!

GOOGLE YOU ******* FOOLZ

IN WEBGL.JS COMMENT THE ON MOUSE DOWN BS

```
  // This keeps the cursor from changing to an I-beam when the user clicks and
  // drags.  It's easier on the eyes.
  function returnFalse() {
    return false;
  }
  document.onselectstart = returnFalse;
  //document.onmousedown = returnFalse;
```